# Can i upload data from multiple datasources to azure DW at same time

Tags: azure, data-warehouse, azure-synapse

Can i retrieve data from multiple data sources to Azure SQL DataWarehouse at the same time using single pipeline?

Comment: Do you need to join this data before you insert it or just a simple data dump would do?

Comment: All the datasources have different schema. I need to transform the data to make it consistent with target db schema. Yes,I may need to join the data.

Comment: Do you have a key to join the data on?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3cPq9FXk-RA

Comment: Are you referring to the ADF pipelines in particular or do you mean any data loading mechanism?

Comment: @hirokibutterfield yes, I am referring to ADF pipelines.

Answer (score 1):

SQL DW can certainly load multiple tables concurrently using external (aka PolyBase) tables, bcp, or insert statements. As hirokibutterfield asks, are you referring to a specific loading tool like Azure Data Factory?

Comment: yes, i am using data factory mechanism(pipelines) to load data into azure data warehouse.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but there you have to mention a copy activity for each of the data source being copied to the azure data warehous.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, and depending on the extent of transformation required, there would be 2 ways to do this. Regardless of the method, the data source does not matter to ADF since your data movement happens via the copy activity which looks at the dataset and takes care of firing the query on the related datasource.

Method 1:

If all your transformation for a table can be done in a SELECT query on the source systems, you can have a set of copy activities specifying SELECT statements. This is the simple approach

Method 2:

If your transformation requires complex integration logic, first use copy activities to copy over the raw data from the source systems to staging tables in the SQLDW instance (Step 1). Then use a set of stored procedures to do the transformations (Step 2).

The ADF datasets which are the output from Step1 will be input datasets to Step 2 in order to maintain consistency.

Comment: Thanks, Akash. I hope it'll be helpfull